# How can i turn single character containting string type to Char in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I am new to Haskell. I have **string** containing single character for example `"A"` or `"3"`. I want to turn it into character to check if it is a digit with `isDigit :: Char -> Bool` function. How can I turn that the string into character?

I tried:

```
isDigit head x
-- and
isDigit take 1 x
```

witch gave me errors:
`Variable not in scope: isDigit :: ([a0] -> a0) -> String -> Bool` and `Variable not in scope: isDigit :: (Int -> [a0] -> [a0]) -> t0 -> String -> Bool`

Comment: `isDigit head x` calls `isDigit` with two arguments (`head` and `x`). You probably want `isDigit (head x)` instead. The expression `isDigit take 1 x` suffers from the same issue (but won't work anyway, since `take` returns a list/string, not a single char).

Comment: Consider using something like `all isDigit` to be robust to mistakenly calling with strings of other lengths. Or, if this is part of a validation pass, something like `singleDigit :: String -> Maybe Int; singleDigit [x] | isDigit x = Just (digitToInt x); singleDigit _ = Nothing`, which returns a failed validation for other lengths, and converts to a more suitable internal representation when validation passes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `isDigit` is defined in `Data.Char`, so you'll need to import that module.  Also, as noted in the comment, the expression `isDigit head x` will try to call `isDigit` with two arguments, `head`, and `x`.  You want to evaluate `head x` and pass that single argument to `isDigit`, so you'll need to write `isDigit (head x)`.  The following program should work:

```
import Data.Char

string1 = "A"
string2 = "3"

main = do
  print $ isDigit (head string1)
  print $ isDigit (head string2)
```

or if you are trying to evaluate this interactively in GHCi, use:

```
ghci> import Data.Char
ghci> isDigit (head "A")
False
ghci> isDigit (head "3")
True
```